# mysql & PDO - row number of sorted and filter results

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am working with a mysql database using PDO and PHP. I have a list of union members in different buildings and I have trying to make it DB query to get the members seniority number.

The database is setup like this:

```
memberID
memberName
memberBuildingNumber
memberHireDate (2000-05-01 as an example)
memberPIN (Used in case of ties between hire date, lower pin is higher seniority)
```

I know the SQL to order the members in the correct order:

```
SELECT * FROM  `members` ORDER BY  `members`.`memberHireDate` ASC, `members`.`memberPIN` ASC WHERE building = buildingB
```

(Yes I know my where statement is wrong)

I am not sure how to go about counting the rows to get the member's position.

For example:

```
1457 John Smith BuildingB 2000-05-01 4745
1875 Jane Smith BuildingB 2000-05-01 4010
1407 Johnny Good BuildingB 2010-08-01 4745
```

so in the above same after I run the second query or what ever I have to do, if i am looking for Jane's seniority number I come back with 1.

Comment: are you sure you want the data to come back in the order of your last block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have actually done is added another column to the member table in the DB. It holds the seniority number and is set by a script. Here is the script if any one is interested in the future.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME', $db_user, $db_password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT memberBuildingNumber FROM BuildingCodes WHERE BuildingCode > 0');
$stmt->execute();

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $results) {
    $memberBuildingNumber = $results['memberBuildingNumber'];

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME', $db_user, $db_password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberBuildingNumber=? ORDER BY memberHireDate ASC, memberPIN ASC');
$stmt->execute(array($memberBuildingNumber));

$seniority = 1;
$memberSeniorityLastUpdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $results) {

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME', $db_user, $db_password);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE members SET memberSeniority=?, memberSeniorityLastUpdate=? WHERE memberID=?');
    $stmt->execute(array($seniority, $memberSeniorityLastUpdate, $results['memberID']));

    $seniority++;
   }
}
```